# Selecionar determinada view para visualização - ASP. NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou aprendendo o ASP.NET MVC e me deparei com uma situação que gostaria da ajuda de vocês.

Tenho um view que mostra o resultado de uma consulta do banco de dados na tela. Cada registro mostrado possui uma identificação (ID), e preciso clicar em alterar para acertar algo que está no que está sendo apresentado, até ai tudo bem.

Porém, por exemplo, o primeiro registro mostrado é para alterar os registros da tabela "A", o segundo registro para alterar os dados da tabela "C", o terceiro da tabela "D" e assim por diante.
O problema é justamente este, existe uma forma de ao clicar no botão Editar, ele apontar para qual view corresponde o erro e abrir esta visualização, ou seja, programar se a view tem erro do tipo 1 abre-se a view "A", se erro tipo 2 abre-se a view "B" e assim por diante.

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? Está tomando algum erro? Atualiza a pergunta para ficar mais fácil de responder.

Comment: Esse comportamento você consegue definir no Controller. Por exemplo, se o botão editar executar um método e enviar o ID x, ele faz y.

Comment: É interessante disponibilizar o código que você descreveu ai!

Comment: Sim, existe uma forma.

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer usando na View usando Razor @HTML.LinkAction, além de criar a Action no controller.

```
@Html.ActionLink("titulo do link", "QualActionQuer", "DeQualcontrollerQuer", new { id = "123" }, null)
```

Ex:

View

```
@Html.ActionLink("titulo do link A", "ActionTabelaA", "AlteraTabelaController", new { id = 1 }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("titulo do link B", "ActionTabelaB", "AlteraTabelaController", new { id = 2 }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("titulo do link C", "ActionTabelaC", "AlteraTabelaController", new { id = 3 }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("titulo do link D", "ActionTabelaD", "AlteraTabelaController", new { id = 4 }, null)
```

Controller

```
public class AlteraTabelaController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ActionTabelaA()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ActionTabelaB()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ActionTabelaC()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ActionTabelaD()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```